# debug java application with TestNG and maven

Tags: java, maven, tdd

I'm creating an applicattion that's work with TDD(Test-driven-development). So I create the projects test before development and my doubt is if i can debug the coding test when i execute with maven (mvn clean package). Cos testing running with maven. 
my development environment is:

- Eclipse Juno
- Maven 3.0.5
- Java 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution if sb needs,

By default, Maven runs your tests in a separate ("forked") process. You can use the maven.surefire.debug property to debug your forked tests remotely, like this:

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug test
```

The tests will automatically pause and await a remote debugger on port 5005. You can then attach to the running tests using Eclipse. You can setup a "Remote Java Application" launch configuration via the menu command "Run" > "Open Debug Dialog..."

If you need to configure a different port, you may pass a more detailed value. For example, the command below will use port 8000 instead of port 5005.

```
mvn -Dmaven.surefire.debug="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000 -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE" test
```

[link to maven page](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/debugging.html)